# Assign values from a column to another column in the correspondent row

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Suppose I have the following table:

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
| a       | 1       |
| b       | 2       |
| c       | 3       |
| d       | 4       |
+---------+---------+
```

What would be the best way to assign the values in `column2`  to `column1` for each row?

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
| a1      | 1       |
| b2      | 2       |
| c3      | 3       |
| d4      | 4       |
+---------+---------+
```

I have tried to use a cursor in order to fetch and save each value in `column2` but I can't figure how to properly assign these values to `column1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update your_table
set column1 = column1 || column2
```

Comment: what if I use an extra field created by a SELECT statement that will be the column that assigns the values (that is just available when fetching from the cursor)? I use a cursor FOR loop and each value in column1 gets all the values in column2 (eg. a1234).

Comment: @PedroN. - please don't ask additional questions in comments. If you have another question then ask another question, and include the relevant code. We aren't very good at guessing.  Thanks.

Comment: @PedroN.: A cursor is really slow. Using a single statement is way faster.